# Visual Studio 2005 + jQuery intellisense

Tags: jquery, visual-studio-2005, intellisense

I'm trying to put my visual studio 2005 profissional with the jQuery doc

I'm importing the core and doc files, but I still don't get the result I hope for...

No intellisence at same...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer:  this doesn't work in **Visual Studio 2005**.

`-vsdoc` is only supported in **Visual Studio 2008**, there was a major overhaul to the javascript intellisense engine in 2008, and the `vsdoc` functionality relies on it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using 2008, but maybe try this method. It's what I do and it works.

Assuming, the script file you're working on is in the same directory as the jQuery vsdoc IntelliSense file, then put this at the top of said script file

```
/// <reference path="jquery-1.4.1-vsdoc.js" />
```

EDIT::

Alright, just a few things then.

1. Make sure that you actually added the jquery to your project, not to the folders of your project. Same goes for the vsdoc.
2. For the vsdoc, make sure it is the same name as the jQuery file + "-vsdoc". For instance, my two files are like this:

   jquery-1.4.1.js

   jquery-1.4.1-vsdoc.js

Comment: Oh, also assuming you're using the same version as I am / same name of the vsdoc file of course.

Comment: I already searched but in vs2005 nobody tolds than is possible

Your steps to vs2008 are ok, but really that doens't work on vs2005

apreciate at same ;)